# Get symfony parameter inside doctrine entity for lifecyclecallback

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to use a lifecycle callback `removeFiles()` within a Doctrine entity. But to delete the files, I need their path that is set in a symfony parameter. Is there a possibility to get the parameter value inside a doctrine entity or do I have to set up an external lifecycle callback?

Comment: No, it's not possible. You must to create a listener service to inject your parameter.

Comment: @PigBall - Few things in programing are impossible.  global $kernel; $kernel->getContainer()->getParameter(''); Of course the fact that something is possible does not mean it's wise.  And of course in this case just using  a php constant might be the answer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#constants-vs-configuration-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @Cerad said, I solved it by defining the path as php class constant. That is even better style because the path should only be changed in very special cases and shouldn't be a parameter therefore.

Answer (score 0):

Entity should be simple stupid, I would not advice you to put logic inside an entity.

You should :

- create a listener on the event postPersit (http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)
- inject your parameter into the listener by constructor in service.yml
- put the logic of deletion inside the listener

Comment: This is pretty much an opinion based answer.  Nothing wrong with having logic inside of an entity.  Check Domain Driven Design for more details.

Comment: I follow the single responsibility rule based on SOLID principe, is not the responsibility of an entity to know how to delete a file.