# How to get an array global variable with symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity 'Team' with an attribute 'country'.
In my database, 'country' is the country's code (en, fr, it..). But I need, for my visitors, to display it as Country Name.

I put in my config/services.yaml this :

```
parameters:
  countries:
    'Afghanistan': 'af'
    'Albanie': 'al'
    'Allemagne': 'de'
    ...
```

It's working perfect for my forms, controllers... but I can't access it from my entities to display associate country name (with __toString()), so my visitors see the country's code and not the country's name. Is there a better way to deal with it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get symfony parameter inside doctrine entity for lifecyclecallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357509/get-symfony-parameter-inside-doctrine-entity-for-lifecyclecallback)

Comment: Entities should be independent from other classes, or config parameters, etc. The entity does not care whether its country code is shown as "Allemagne" or "Germany" or simply as code to the user. This should be the controllers responsibility which presents the entity to the user.

Comment: @yivi it's not exactly that, andrei thank you so i'll no more use my toString in my form I think it's a bad practice so. Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You should better use a service which takes over the processing of the data. The service can be injected in your controller. In the controller, you can call public methods of the service and the return-value can be used in the controller. The dependency injection concept is well explained here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

I can't recommend putting static data into Symfony this way. If there are a lot of countries involved, it will soon stop being funny.

For working with countries and locales, there is also a Symfony component ready-to-use, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31079286)